# I want to install both WiFi drivers

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

Just installed Ubuntu on my laptop ([Lenovo y700 14ISK](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/y700-series/y700-14-inch/)).

I am unable to get my WIFI working. Going through multiple forum posts, I figured out that i need to find the WIFI chipset type using commands like `lspci -v`, and install the controller drivers accordingly.

However, I am confused with response received for `lspci -v` as it seems to be returning both network as well as ethernet controller. But, There is no identifier that clearly states wireless chipset. Any help with figuring out right chipset and getting WIFI driver installed is highly appreciated.

The following is response from `lspci -v`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 3166 (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4210
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a2200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
Device 524a (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 524a
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a2100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3836
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a2004000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: What kernel are you using, in terminal `uname -a` Thanks

Comment: I just read that need to update kernel to 4.2 from my current 3.19.x? Can you share the steps for the same? Thanks

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. We need at least the PCI device type IDs of the wireless network adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You could update to the 4.2 kernel or install the latest backports, installing the 4.2 kernel is a better option as backports would have to be reinstalled with every new 3.19 kernel until the patch that enables your device is merged with the Ubuntu 3.19 kernel series

You will likely need firmware if the 4.2 kernel doesn't already have it

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-15.227938.0.tgz
tar zxvf iwlwifi-7265-ucode-15.227938.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-7265-ucode-15.227938.0.tgz
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265-15.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3165-15.ucode
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265-15.ucode /lib/firmware/
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

After updating kernel to 4.2 or higher, go to [the Intel Wi-Fi Adapters Linux Support Page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) and download the appropriate drivers for your hardware (AC 3165 worked for my hardware which is identical to the OP's). After downloading, follow the instructions listed in the README file in the downloaded tar file. This doesn't work for the Ethernet controller but it'll get wi-fi working. I'll edit later once I get the Ethernet controller working as well. Just need to find the correct drivers from Realtek.